# Calling a Hash Class Function

Tags: c++, hash

I am trying to create my own hash class. However after countless tries I cannot get my program to work correctly. I believe that there is an error in me calling the function, however I am not quite sure. Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong and possibly show me how to fix it?

***hash.h***

```
#include <iostream>

class MyHash {
public:
    MyHash();
    int hashCode(char, char);
};
```

***hash.cpp***

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Hash.h"

MyHash::MyHash() {}

int MyHash::hashCode(char first_letter, char last_letter) {
    int hash = 0;
    int ascii = 1;

    hash = ((ascii * first_letter) + (ascii * last_letter)) % 23;

    return (hash);
}
```

***driver.cpp***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Hash.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> words;
    int first_letter;
    int last_letter;
    string word;
    int n = 0;
    int hash = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << " Please enter a word: ";
        cin >> word;
        words.push_back(word);
    }

    vector<string>::iterator itr = words.begin();
    for (; itr != words.end(); itr++) {
        first_letter = *itr[n].begin();
        last_letter = *itr[n].rbegin();
        cout << endl << " " << first_letter << " " << last_letter << endl;
        hash = hashCode(first_letter, last_letter) cout << hash << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Soo... given some known input, what do you see and what do you expect to see?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you wrapping your function inside a class? It's completely arbitrary to define a class, place no data whatsoever inside of it then try to call the function from it without declaring any objects.

```
int hashCode(char first_letter, char last_letter) {
    int hash = 0;
    int ascii = 1;

    hash = ((ascii * first_letter) + (ascii * last_letter)) % 23;

    return (hash);
}
```

If you wanted to use a class, you need to have a structure along the lines of:

```
class myHash{
  public:
    myHash();
    insert();
    remove();
  private:
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    hash();
    rehash();
};
```

Comment: I need to do it for a college class, and this is only the first function. I am just testing one thing at a time.

Comment: @NinjaZ well you can't call the function directly, you need to create an object first. e.g. `myHash obj; obj.hashCode();`

Comment: How would I go about including my hashCode() function hash.h that way and defining it in hash.cpp? Any additional information would be greatly appreciated, as I am not quite familiar with class and object creation.

Answer (score 1):

So to get over the compilation problem and not change the overall structure of the program you'll need to change your call to `hashDode(...)` to be `MyHash::hashCode(...)` and also change your declaration of `int hashCode(char, char);` to be `static int hashCode(char, char);`.

Youcan't just call a function defined in some scope and expect the compiler to figure it out, you need to give some indication as to where the function is.  Since it's a class method you need to specify a class object or the class itself.

The `static` keyword will allow you to call the function without an object, which is OK in this case since you don't have any data in your object.